# How to get the second last string in C#

Tags: c#, string

Example1:

```
string input = "Village Siaban  WDT no.39 91308 Semporna Sabah";
```

Example2:

```
string input = "Village Hw WDT no.39 91308 Sandakan Sarawak";
```

How do I extract the second last words and print it out. For this case from the Example1 is Semporna and Example2 is Sandakan.

Comment: What's a word exactly?

Comment: I meant words. Sorry. How do I extract second last words from both example. The words are "Semporna" from example 1 and "Sandakan" from example 2.

Comment: @MaXi32: check my answer below, is that you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1:** You can `Split` the String using `space` delimeter to get all words from String.
**Step 2:** You can use the `WordsLength-2` to get the 2'nd word from Last.

Try This:

```
string input = "Village Siaban  WDT no.39 91308 Semporna Sabah";

var words = input.Split(' ');
var reqWord = "";
if(words.Length > 1)
   reqWord = words[words.Length-2];
```

Comment: Will throw an exception if the sentence is one word long.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Good Point ,Thanks .Edited my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sudhakar Tillapudi. and Wiktor

Comment: Sorry, I have one more question regarding to this. What if the input is like this:

Comment: @MaXi32: sorry i didn't get you, like ?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't put a new line. Accidentally pressed enter. It's okay. I got it now. Thanks a lot. marked as answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun:

```
string input = "Village Siaban  WDT no.39 91308 Semporna Sabah";
input.Split(' ').Reverse().Take(2).Last();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string input = "Village Siaban  WDT no.39 91308 Semporna Sabah";

string secondToLastWord = input.Split(' ').Reverse().ElementAt(1).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

why not using a regex?

```
   var word = Regex.Match(input, ".* ([^ ]*) [^ ]*").Groups[1];
```